# JavaScript, Jquery find index of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I building slide, and I need am stack at following problem - How can I found position (index) in the array when a tag is clicked? This part of the code is getting all a tag

```
 this.thumbs = this.nav.find('a');
```

How to go from there?
And also, there is another problem - I need to toggle class of the div inside a tag (when a tag is clicked div tag needs to get class promo_tumb_current and the one which has that tag need to loose it).

HTML code:

```
<div class="promo_tumbs col_12">
    <div data-dir="prev" class="prev"></div>
    <div data-dir="next" class="next"></div>
    <div class="promo_tumbs_centar">
        <a href="#first"><div class="promo_tumb promo_tumb_current"></div></a>
        <a href="#second"><div class="promo_tumb"></div></a>
        <a href="#thrid"><div class="promo_tumb"></div></a>
        <a href="#fourh"><div class="promo_tumb"></div></a>
        <a href="#fifth"><div class="promo_tumb"></div></a>
        <a href="#fifth"><div class="promo_tumb"></div></a>
        <a href="#fifth"><div class="promo_tumb"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
                function Slider(container, nav){
                    this.container = container;
                    this.nav = nav;

                    this.li = this.container.find('li');
                    this.li_width = this.li.first().width();
                    this.li_len = this.li.length;

                    this.thumbs = this.nav.find('a');

                    this.current = 0;
                }

                Slider.prototype.transition = function (coords){
                    this.container.stop().animate({
                        'margin-left' : coords || -(this.current * this.li_width)
                    })
                }

                Slider.prototype.set_current = function(dir){
                    var pos = this.current;
                    if (dir === 'next') {pos++}
                    else if (dir === 'prev') {pos--}                
                    this.current = (pos < 0) ? this.li_len - 1 : pos % this.li_len;

                    return pos;
                }

                var slider = new Slider($('div.promo_inner ul'), $('div.promo_tumbs'));
                    slider.nav.find('div').on('click', function(){                               
                    if ($(this).attr("data-dir") === undefined ) {
                        var index = slider.thumbs.index();

                        console.log(index)
                    } else {
                         slider.set_current($(this).data('dir'));                    
                    }               
                    slider.transition();


                })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is

http://api.jquery.com/index/

For example, within your event handler (where this is the clicked a tag):

```
var index = thumbs.index($(this))
```

Comment: Your code is backwards. You're searching for the index of `this` in `thumbs`, so it should be: `var index = thumbs.index(this);`.

Comment: When I try this I get -1 for a result. I need to add slider before thumbs `var index = $(this).index(slider.thumbs)` or it will produce error.

Comment: @Sasha probably because of the error noticed by Anthony Grist. Sample code fixed, sorry

Comment: I am still getting -1 as a result o.O?

Comment: It means that the clicked link is not in the "thumbs" selection. You have to use the debugger to find why... Probaly something stupid somewhere. Please check that this is actually a link, and that thumbs is actually your collection of links.

Comment: @Sasha The `click` event handler is triggered from all `<div>` elements inside `nav`, so isn't the link itself, so you can't just use `this` - use `$(this).parent('a')` instead. Incidentally, it's also being triggered from the `prev` and `next` divs, as well as the one that contains the links themselves, which you probably don't want. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6R9Wg/) demo.

Comment: It working, but I get two values - the right one and -1 (-1 is always there). How to loose -1?